# Linear Referencing along a polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I'm trying to use the "Locate Features along Routes." I have a simple polyline and I have an excel sheet of To and From miles.  The excel sheet has no X&Y coordinates.  The excel sheet has the information on where the breaks are based on miles.  I want the geoprocessing to take care of polygons along the route and then add in the excel file.  How do I do this?

Comment: Is line data already in linearly referenced? i.e. do you have the same road ids between the road layer and your excel event table. For example in your line layer, you should have a route_control_section_ID or something similar to it while in your polygon you'd have the same or equivalent that tells you at which ID point the "event" begins and where it "ends". If that's not the case, then please provided more detail (field lists, screenshots, etc) from both layers